# Is that possible to run HADOOP and copy a file from local fs to HDFS in JAVA BUT without installing Hadoop on file system?

Tags: java, linux, maven, hadoop

I have NOT installed `hadoop` on my Linux file System. I would like to run `hadoop` and copy the file from `local file system` to `HDFS` WITHOUT installing `hadoop` on my Linux file System. I have created a sample code but it says "wrong FS, expected file:///". Any help for this?

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;

/**
 * Created by Ashish on 23/4/15.
*/
public class SampleHadoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://192.168.1.170:54310/"),configuration);
            fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("./part-m-00000"), new Path("hdfs://192.168.1.170:54310/user/hduser/samplefile"));
            fs.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          System.out.println("Exception "+ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

POM.XML

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sqoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.99.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sqoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqoop</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sqoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqoop-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.99.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I looked for all possible solution and found following:

```
...
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource(new Path("/home/user/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("/home/user/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
```

BUT in my case I do not want to install `hadoop` on my liunx file system so I could not specify such path like "home/user/hadoop". I prefer if I could make it run only using jar files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right choice for your use case will be using **WebHDFS** api. It supports the systems running outside Hadoop clusters to access and manipulate the HDFS contents. It doesn't require the client systems to have hadoop binaries installed, you could manipulate remote hdfs over http using CURL itself.

Please refer,

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/webhdfs.html

http://hortonworks.com/blog/webhdfs-%E2%80%93-http-rest-access-to-hdfs/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please provide me link Hadoop WebHDFS REST API's java client as I am Java Programmer?

Comment: welcome..actually WebHDFS service is managed within the hadoop cluster itself, we dont have to have any hadoop lib on client side. kindly check if WebHDFS is enabled , if not then refer above url to enable it. Once it is running you may use **apache httpclient** to interact with the WebHDFS rest service from your Java code..

Answer (score 0):

You will need a hadoop installation in order to copy files to and from HDFS.

If you have a system with **hadoop installed on remote system** within the same network, **you can copy the remote hdfs files to your local filesystem (no hadoop installation required on local system)**. Just replace your IP with remote system's IP.

Anyway you will need atleast one system with hadoop installation to use hadoop functions.

Comment: I did the same. As you can see in my above sample code, `hadoop` installed on another system within the network whose ip is 192.168.1.170 but it says "wrong FS, expected file:///". What will be the path of core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml? How to point the remote path of site.xml and hdfs-site.xml in configuration?